# Can't create a variable arguments iterator & decorator class (advanced)

Tags: javascript, iterator, decorator

I have a Javascript class that receives an object as argument:

```js
function convertible(args){
  var self = this;
  $.extend(self, {
    /* many functions that manipulate data */
  });
}
```

Usually, this class is called with an object with this structure

```js
var result = new convertible({
  'x':[{'a':[/*...*/],'c':'asdf'}/*...*/],
  'y':[{'a':[/*...*/],'c':10}/*...*/],
  'z':[{'a':[/*...*/],'c':255},{'a':[],'c':255}/*...*/]
});
```

where the number of properties in this object is variable per request and the content of `c` and `a` are unknown. Sometimes, inside `a` will have some special objects, that need to be converted, like:

```js
var result = new convertible({
  'z':[{'a':[0, {'PF':/*string to be eval'led*/}],'c':255}]
});
```

doing it recursively, to "process" all the arguments, sometimes in Webkit leads to a RangeError Maximum Call Stack reached error, so, instead of manually iterating using a `for..in` loop, I'm trying to conceive a helper iterator class along with the decorator pattern, so when I do `args.get(0)` or `args.foreach(function(){})` I get the 'converted' PF object (that is an inline function that gets eval'led). The problem is, sometimes the `a` part is like this (indented for clearer visualization):

```js
var result = new convertible({
  'z':[
    { 
      'a':[
        [{'PF':/*string to be eval'led*/}],
        {'PF':{/*another object that MIGHT have PF inside*/}}
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

because of the dynamic nature of the generated code, it causes some 'inconsistencies' for the `PF` variable. And when the type is 'PR', it's a nested `z` object inside the `a`. Like this:

```js
var result = new convertible({
  'z':[
    { 
      'a':[
        {
          'PR': {
            'z': [
              {'a': [/*...*/], 'c': 0}
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

My head short-circuited already trying to conceive this iterator/decorator class.

Comment: When you do the for..in iterator, do you iterate through all the properties or do you check for hasOwnProperty?

Comment: check with hasOwnProperty, please focus on the question people, I lint my code.